# The BaseAdapter in android

Tags: android, button

How to obtain the current item using `getView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup arg2)` based on position?
There is a button in every item. When click the button, I will obtain the button object and change the attribute. How to obtain?

About all button they can monitor. 
Now the problem is about the single button.

Comment: if you using an anonymous OnClickListener you should make your Listview variable final then you'll be able to access it in the anonymous defination of your event, then just use the position variable to get the select object.

Comment: Is your `Adapter` holding buttons or Layouts which contain buttons as their attributes?